Did the English Koren-Steinsaltz Utilize an Erroneous Translation for Meilah 7b?
The Talmud in Meilah 7b records a back and forth between R Yochanan and Reish Lakish regarding a position of R Akiva. R Yochanan finally gets the best of Reish Lakish and states (per Sefaria Meilah
7b
The William Davidson Talmud
(Koren - Steinsaltz):

אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן: קַצֵּצְתִּינּוּן לְרַגְלוֹהִי דְיָנוֹקָא.
Rabbi Yoḥanan said in this regard: We have cut off the legs of the
child, i.e., I have refuted Reish Lakish’s opinion by raising a
difficulty that eliminates the basis for his opinion.

Why did he say, 'we have cut off'? He refuted R Lakish on his own! I have checked other translations which use "I."

Off the top of my head, I imagine he was probably using some colloquial expression.

I looked on Sefaria, and, indeed, there seems to be a problem with Koren's translation. The German translation says "Ich habe dem Knaben die Beine abgehauen."

It could be a total power move based on מלחמתה של תורה. No holds barred. R Yochanan uses the Royal We. He thus refers to himself in a regal fashion. He then refers to R Lakish as a freshman . We have cut off the legs of the newbie. Reminds me of what chazal say regarding את והב בסופה. את והב בסופה אמר רבי חייא בר אבא: אפילו האב ובנו, הרב ותלמידו שעוסקין בתורה בשער אחד, נעשים אויבים זה את זה

In fact he does say "I" in the singular.  קַצֵּצְתִּ-ינּוּן  means I cut them off (as opposed to קצצנא or קצצינן which would mean "we cut off"). The more familiar suffix for "them" in the Babylonian Talmud would be קצצתינהו, but Rabbi Yochanan is speaking in his own (Israeli) dialect which is more common in the Targumim (וְשִׁנַּנְתָּם לְבָנֶיךָ = וּתְתַנֵּינוּן לִבְנָךְ).

The English Koren - Steinsaltz has messed up R' Steinsaltz's Hebrew translation many times. Here, R' Steinsaltz translates it as I, and Koren changed it to we. They do something similar in Niddah 19a.
I forgot the exact location but somewhere in Eruvin, R' Steinsaltz explains a Gemara like Rashi does and Koren completely deviates from his translation and makes up their own explanation (which I didn't find anywhere else when I quickly looked around).

Thank you ... makes sense!

If you didn't research properly, how can you be sure about your strong statement "completely made up", which is not an ideal thing to say without confidence? Did you see ba's answer?

Completely made up wasn't about here, it was about Eruvin. Also it's not referring to their commentary but to them not being faithful to R' Steinsaltz's translation

Koren's translation is led by R Tzvi Hersh Weinreb (also a past Executive VP of the OU), an acknowledged scholar, in consultation with R Meni Steinsaltz, the son of R Adin. It is likely they had good reasons to deviate here or there from the original translation. Errors are always possible but one should judge favorably

I would be more likely to judge favorably if I hadn't emailed them (regarding the Gemara in Niddah and the translation of ירוק) and they responded that technically it can be correct (even though no one that I have seen defined it the way they had, but many have specifically pointed out unlike them such as Tosfot and R Steinsaltz also translated it as yellow). Digging into a mistake didn't seem so intellectually honest and slightly defensive.
